# spring jdbc data returned by NamedParameterJdbcTemplate not in sorted order

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

When I run the following SQL, the data is returned in the expected sort order (last_run_date, ascending):

```
select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ( select id, job_name, description, enabled, last_run_date, last_run_msg, current_status, userid from JOBS ORDER BY last_run_date asc ) a   where ROWNUM <= 5 ) where rnum > 0
```

However, when I run the following Java/Spring code, the data is not in the sort order specified.

```
private final String GET_ALL_JOBS_JQGRID_SQL = "select * from " +
            "( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from " + 
            "( select id, job_name, description, enabled, last_run_date, last_run_msg, current_status, userid from JOBS ORDER BY :sidx asc ) a " + 
            "  where ROWNUM <= :max_row_to_fetch ) " +
            "where rnum > :min_row_to_fetch";

private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jobStatusParameterJdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

        this.dataSource = dataSource;

        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        this.jobStatusParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

I pass in last_run_date, 10 and 0 as the parameter values.

```
public List<Job> getAllJobs(String sidx, int max_row_to_fetch, int min_row_to_fetch) {

        SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("sidx", sidx)
        .addValue("max_row_to_fetch", max_row_to_fetch)
        .addValue("min_row_to_fetch", min_row_to_fetch);


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List <Job> jobs = jobStatusParameterJdbcTemplate.query(GET_ALL_JOBS_JQGRID_SQL, namedParameters, new JobRowMapper());

        return jobs;
    }

private static class JobRowMapper implements RowMapper
    {
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException 
        {
            int jobId = rs.getInt(1);

            String jobName = rs.getString(2);
            String jobDesc = rs.getString(3);
            String jobEnabled = rs.getString(4);
            Date jobLastRunDate = rs.getDate(5);
            String jobLastRunMsg = rs.getString(6);
            String jobCurrentStatus = rs.getString(7);
            String userid = rs.getString(8);

            Job job = new Job();
            job.setId(jobId);
            job.setJob_name(jobName);
            job.setDescription(jobDesc);
            job.setEnabled(jobEnabled);
            job.setLast_run_date(jobLastRunDate);
            job.setLast_run_msg(jobLastRunMsg);
            job.setCurrent_status(jobCurrentStatus);
            job.setUserid(userid);

            return job;
        }
```

Comment: If JOBS ORDER BY :sidx asc that is your sorted order then it will be ignored since it is inside another select statement, actually you can remove it and you should have the same behavior.

Comment: But why does it work fine when I execute the SQL by itself outside of Spring?

Comment: Can you add the whole sql statement you use directly? Outside Spring you mean directly to the sql console? I assume it is mysql

Comment: setting a named parameter does not mean a replacement.

Comment: @porfiriopartida The "final" SQL would be:  select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ( select id, job_name, description, enabled, last_run_date, last_run_msg, current_status, userid from JOBS ORDER BY last_run_date asc ) a   where ROWNUM <= 5 ) where rnum > 0

Comment: @erencan Can you be less cryptic?

Comment: can you post `jobStatusParameterJdbcTemplate`? i mean named parameters may not be used in order by clause.

Comment: @erencan I suspect that is the problem.  I tried using a PreparedStatement, and it didn't work that way either.  The only way I've gotten this to work is to build the SQL statement as a String and execute it as a Statement.

Comment: I think so. If you post `jobStatusParameterJdbcTemplate` codes. i will make sure of it.

Comment: @erencan I've updated my code above to include the declaration and init of that object.

Comment: This person is essentially having the same problem as me.  The answer is that you can't specify the ORDER By as a parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991491/spring-jdbc-data-returned-by-namedparameterjdbctemplate-not-in-sorted-order